# Apache Avro - type values for Record complex types

Tags: schema, avro

In the Avro schema:

```
{"namespace": "example.avro",
 "type": "record",
 "aliases": ["person"],
 "name": "User",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "favorite_number",  "type": ["int", "null"]},
     {"name": "favorite_color", "type": ["string", "null"]}
 ]
}
```

I would like to add a new field `dummy` which has a complex type of `array`. So would the below be correct?

```
{"namespace": "example.avro",
 "type": "record",
 "aliases": ["person"],
 "name": "User",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "favorite_number",  "type": ["int", "null"]},
     {"name": "favorite_color", "type": ["string", "null"]},
     {"name": "dummy","type":{"type":"array", "items":"string"}
 ]
}
```

I am thinking it's correct because for `type` it can be a Schema (either String,JSON Object, or JSON array). Since, `array` is a JSON array, shouldn't the above be allowed for `dummy`?

Comment: Schema looks fine except that you are missing a `}` after `{"name": "dummy","type":{"type":"array", "items":"string"}`. Is there any specific issue you are facing when using this schema? If so, try to share the details of error along with a sample record you are trying handle with this schema.

Comment: Also, since you are appending a new field, you'll have to provide a default value for your field for backward compatibility. Reference: https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/avro.html#compatibility-types